# Combinatorics and Generating Functions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $d_n$ = ${N \choose n}{M \choose 0} + {N \choose n-1}{M \choose 1} + {N \choose n-2}{M \choose 2}+...+{N \choose0}{M \choose n}$. Using the binomial theorem prove that $(1+x)^N(1+x)^M$ is the generating function fo $d_n$. Conclude that $d_n$ = ${N+M \choose n}$.
I have no idea how to complete this problem or where to even begin.

Comment: See exercise 10.1.8 [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/CombText/ch-10.pdf), which is this problem, but with hints.

Answer (score 1):

You should know from the binomial theorem that

$$(1+x)^N=\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}kx^k$$

and

$$(1+x)^M=\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{M}kx^k\;,$$

so that

$$(1+x)^N(1+x)^M=\left(\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{M}kx^k\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

Then use the fact that

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}b_k\right)=\sum_{k\ge 0}c_k\;,$$

where

$$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;,$$

to show that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1)$ is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{N}k\binom{M}{n-k}=d_n\;.$$